# Deploy raw web application files to azure using command line

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, publish

I need to copy web app files directly to azure & publish to web site **through command line.**(the same action can be done using WebMatrix tool as explained here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-using-webmatrix/)

I'm expecting that it needs Azure CLI to do this. Can anyone throw some light on best way to this (or) direct solution for this requirement.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn642480.aspx) for CLI. [Here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/automate-everything) you will find all the other approaches that can be employed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good list of how to deploy to a web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/. Git is very easy to use and can be managed directly from cmd. You can access the REST API via Azure CLI but you can't change individual files for an existing site.

If you want a very general purpose way to change deploy files, you could also do the following via the Kudu REST API: download the file from your website using invoke-webrequest (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx), modify the file using standard text fie processing, and then upload the file by zipping it, and then calling the Kudu REST API (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip). You can authenticate against this REST API using basic auth with credentials that you get from the publishing settings.